# Html table - row highlight on mouse hover for specific column

Tags: html, css

Let's take example table:

```
<style>
    table tr:hover td{
        background-color: #8888FF;
    }
</style>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>header</td>
        <td>12 </td>
        <td>13 </td>
        <td>14 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>header</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>header</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>header</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>44</td>
    </tr
</table>
```

In this example, complete row is highlighted on any column mouse hover.

Is it possible to highlight complete row only on mouse hover for 1st column using just css? Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiSXq.png).

Comment: Do you mean highlight on the first COLUMN hover?

Comment: add classes ... right now I work ok, it hightlight all ... table tr:hover td ... on hover. then You will get table tr.my_class td:hover{}

Comment: @YevheniiShlapak Sorry, there was a mistake in the question. You are right, I mean 1st column hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `~` selector with `:first-child`. Like this:

```
table tr td:first-child:hover ~ td {
    background-color: #8888FF;
}
  table tr td:first-child:hover {
    background-color: #8888FF;
}
```

P.S. Maybe this is not the best approach, but I don't know any others.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Almost there, now row is highlighted on 1st column mouse hover. But not all cells, 1st cell int the row is not highlighted. Is it possible to highlight also the 1st cell?

Comment: @AndrejK I've edited an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer. Try this!

```
<style>
    table tr td:first-child:hover ~ td, td:first-child:hover{
        background-color: #8888FF;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: See the attached screenshot and edit your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Sorry, I had a typo in my question - there was "row" instead of "column". I changed it. So I need to highlight whole row on 1st column hover.

Comment: @AndrejK Check my edited answer. Worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm. Unfortunately I cannot chose 2 answers :-(

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
    table tr td:nth-child(1):hover{
                                    background-color: #8888FF;
                                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  td:first-child:hover ~ td, td:first-child:hover{
        background-color: #8888FF;
    }
```

I think that this is what you are looking for